# Send dynamic, localized push to groups of Android/iOS with Firebase HTTP protocol

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

What is the best way of sending push notifications to a large number of devices (~50 000 Android and iOS devices)? There are currently two supported locales in our app and the contents of the push are not going to be known to the devices (can't use predefined resources).

We were thinking of using `topics`, but it seems we can't target a specific language, and so we need to create separate topics for each language. Also, we probably want to send different content to Android and iOS due to different capabillities, and so need separate topics for platforms. To Android we want to send data push to handle them ourself, iOS 9 can't do that if I understand the documentation correctly. Even so we might still want to target a specific platform with specific information.

So it seems we would need four topics to one
"actual" topic, eg a news topic would be something like:

```
android-en-news
android-se-news
ios-en-news
ios-se-news
```

This scales very poorly, and provides difficulties when user switch locale since we would need to unsubscribe to one topic and subscribe to another. Is there a better method to achieve the same goal, or is there a plan to add eg filter to the FCM API, so we could send to a specific language/platform/app-version?

We first and foremost intend to use the HTTP protocol from our server.

Comment: Looks like you've done your homework quite well. AFAIK, this is the simplest way to go. The more *personal customizations* you need, the more you have to work on to implement it. For the *plan to filter the FCM API*, I don't think there's anything like taht at the moment.

Comment: @AL. I think you are right. Though I would hope there is at least a plan to add such functionality to FCM HTTP API since you can target an app/language/version through the Firebase Console.

Comment: Sounds cool if it is applied to the HTTP API. You could file a [Feature Request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for it. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @Love, was searching around and managed to get back to this post. There is now a feature to send using a single payload to different platforms called [Platform Overrides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#customizing_a_message_across_platforms). The localization option isn't there yet, but this might reduce the number of topics you already have. Cheers!